# What's wrong with this bogus proof?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification

[image]

What is the mistake here? Is it matter of the unit?

Comment: Yes, the units don’t match across the 2nd equals sign

Comment: Yes, you have to square the unit. Conversion of squared units is different: if 100 cents is a dollar, then $100^2$ cents squared is a dollar squred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clearly see the fallacy if you keep track of the units:

- In the second equality, $\$0.01 = \$0.1\times \$0.1$ is not true, if you are doing units.
- Even if the second equality were true, the third one gives problems: since $c=\$/100$, you have 
  $$
  (\$0.1)^2=\left(\frac c{100}\,0.1\right)^2=\frac{c^2}{100}\times\frac1{10}=\frac{c^2}{1000}. 
  $$
  This is not $(10c)^2=100c^2$.

In conclusion, two equalities are bogus, and so is the argument.

Answer (score 6):

$\$0.01=(\sqrt{\$}0.1)^2$, not $(\$0.1)^2$.